# @SpringBootTest with @Import also loads XML Config (beans.xml)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an xml config (`integration-context-test.xml`) with 2 beans (`BeanA.class`, `BeanB.class`)

`BeanA` is a normal Java class with no annotations and `BeanB` is a spring integration component  (`int-http:inbound-gateway`)

I create a test with `@SpringBootTest` and `@ImportResource("integration-context-test.xml")`. When I run the test, I see that `integration-context-test` is not loaded. To fix this, I have to add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` (*since `@SpringBootTest` does not include `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, unlike `@SpringBootApplication`*) .

What confuses me is the following:

If I add `@SpringBootTest` and `@Import(BeanA.class)` **instead of** `@EnableAutoConfiguration` then `integration-context-test` is loaded, the spring integration component is triggered. How is this working? How is `@Import` registering the `BeanB` defined in `integration-context-test.xml`? Isn't `@Import` supposed to load only `BeanA` ?

Comment: I doubt you did `@ImportResource("integration-context-test")` but rather `@ImportResource("integration-context-test.xml")`. Normally `@SpringBootTest` will automatically detect your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class and configure what is needed for the test accordingly. However as you are specifying things explicitly this is not going to happen, nor is auto config going to happen.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I updated the question with `@ImportResource("integration-context-test.xml")`. That answers why @EnableAutoConfiguration is required on @SpringBootTest. I am still not clear why `@Import(BeanA.class)` loads XML Config beans (integration-context-test.xml)